# Quarkus: "no tenant identifier specified" in callback

Tags: callback, multi-tenant, quarkus

I try to add multi-tenancy support for my Quarkus app, following [Quarkus hibernate-orm doc](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm) (see last section).
I have my `CustomTenantResolver` class and configure in `application.properties`, with multiple data sources, but no named persistent unit, see below:

```
# Default data source
quarkus.hibernate-orm.datasource=master
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=none

quarkus.hibernate-orm.multitenant=DATABASE

# ----- Tenant 'master' (default) ---------------
quarkus.datasource."master".db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource."master".username=postgres
quarkus.datasource."master".password=password
quarkus.datasource."master".jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_master

# ----- Tenant 'test' ---------------------------
quarkus.datasource.test.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.test.username=postgres
quarkus.datasource.test.password=password
quarkus.datasource.test.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_test
```

Everything works fine for Web Services APIs functions - based on incoming web service calls, I can extract and supply tenant identifier for DB access.

Problem is, my app also needs to use callback method to listen on messages coming from Apache Pulsar queue. When a message comes in and triggers this callback, any DB access in this method will give this exception:

```
SessionFactory configured for multi-tenancy, but no tenant identifier specified: org.hibernate.HibernateException: SessionFactory configured for multi-tenancy, but no tenant identifier specified
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.<init>(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.<init>(AbstractSessionImpl.java:29)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1282)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:472)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.session.TransactionScopedSession.acquireSession(TransactionScopedSession.java:86)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.session.TransactionScopedSession.persist(TransactionScopedSession.java:138)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.session.ForwardingSession.persist(ForwardingSession.java:53)
... (snipped)
```

Apparently my `CustomTenantResolver` class was not called during this listener callback as the callback is another fresh thread, hence no tenant id is supplied.

Do I miss anything? How about the scheduler in Quarkus - how does it support multi-tenancy in scheduled jobs? 
Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when pulling messages from JMS. The cause of the issue is that `io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.tenant.HibernateCurrentTenantIdentifierResolver` ( which `implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver` and as the doc says `Maps from the Quarkus {@link TenantResolver} to the Hibernate {@link CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver} model` ) expects a request context to be active before calling our implementation of `TenantResolver`, as shown here:

```java
        // Make sure that we're in a request
        if (!Arc.container().requestContext().isActive()) {
            return null;
        }
        TenantResolver resolver = tenantResolver(persistenceUnitName);
        String tenantId = resolver.resolveTenantId();
```

I solved it on my app by, first, enabling the request context on the JMS consumer:

```java
Arc.container().requestContext().activate();
```

and, second,  using a `ThreadLocal` to "pass" the current tenant id to the TenantResolver that will be called later by Hibernate ( through the HibernateCurrentTenantIdentifierResolver instance):

```java
  CurrentTenantLocal.setCurrentTenantId("public");
```

On my `TenantResolver` ( the class that `implements TenantResolver` ) I resolve the tenant from either an injected `JsonWebToken jwt` when it comes from a WebRequest, or using the ThreadLocal when consuming from JMS:

```java
    if ( CurrentTenantLocal.getCurrentTenantId() != null ) {
      return CurrentTenantLocal.getCurrentTenantId();
    }
```

Caveats:

- Note that I haven't done an exhaustive search of the possible side effects of activating the request context... but I have no problems so far.